# Get rid of unnecessary map and data from shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have loaded the base map from Esri's default provided maps but it's for the whole world, and I have got the roads data too, but its for whole continent.

I only need for one city I am going to be working on to save my RAM.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details about how you "loaded the base map from esri's defualt provided maps", please?  It sounds like you added a basemap from ArcGIS Online but then your title suggests that this is a shapefile (which it is not).

Comment: Did you load the esri streetmap mxd provided in data and maps?

Answer (score 2):

The basemaps from Esri are (typically) only used for background, not analysis. I'm going to focus on your roads data, and assume that you have it in either a feature class or shapefile.

There are at least three ways of limiting what a tool will analyze:

1. Select the road features you want to analyze. Run the tool. Most tools will only process for the selected features. (This can be tedious if you're going to be running a lot of different tools on the same subset of data.)
2. Select the roads that you are interested in keeping. [Export to a new feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000t000000), ensure that you have *Selected features* checked in the dialog box.
3. Use a [Definition Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000) to limit which records of the layer are *shown* (and analyzed) within ArcMap. For example, if there's a field in the table for `CITYNAME`, the query would be like `"CITYNAME" = 'MyCity'`.

The first two methods are easier if you have to select by location or manually select what roads you want to keep. Definition queries can be easier if you don't want to create a new feature to analyze, but they do require that you have an attribute to filter with.